# How to convert sequence numbers first two digit before points using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In myscenario, I am receiving numbers lat and long like 423527217 and 712234343.This value mapvoew coordination it not taking as a lat and long. So, I would like to covert `42.3527217` and `71.2234343`.

How to convert above mentioned numbers to first two digits after points?

Comment: Is the number of digits always the same i.e. will you always receive a 9 digit number for lat and long?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do it like as shown below

```js
const num1 = 423527217;

const convert = num => {
  //Convert to string and split
  let numStr = `${num}`.split("");
  //Using splice add '.' at index 2
  numStr.splice(2, 0, '.');
  //Join and parse and then return
  return parseFloat(numStr.join(""));
}

console.log(convert(num1));
const num2 = 712234343;
console.log(convert(num2));
```

Comment: Can someone explain why the downvote and what's wrong in the code. So that it'll be helpful for me also to learn and understand. Thanks